# SharePoint Simple WebPart Lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying (and failing) to get a very simple webpart working.

1. button which when pressed adds list item into custom list (this works great)
2. list out all the items from the custom list (this also works great)
3. the problem is that when i display the items and add a new item i need to refresh twice to get the listing to display the item that i am trying to display.  What is the correct lifecycle that i need to follow with createchildcontrols, onload etc so that when i click the button and it adds a record in that the listing will display the newly inserted item.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this..moving the listing to pre-render has corrected the issue.

Comment: Cool, glad that solved the problem. I've added an answer so we can get this archived xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a case of setting the control values or forcing databinding in OnLoad; this is before the "add item" occurs which is *before* the new item has been added.

I recommend using [Data-Binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.ASPX) and ensuring databinding in PreRender<sup>1</sup>. As long all the controls follow this later-databinding it should Just Work. Otherwise, manually force update/databind the appropriate controls *after* (or in response to) the "add item" action.

The [Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is the same as for ASP.NET WebForms, and summarized for the issue:

```
- "OnLoad"
- PostBack Actions such as "OnClick"
- "PreRender"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Databinding in PreRender works - even though it initially seems like it ought not to - because ASP.Net controls will [Catch-Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#catch_up_events_for_added_controls) as required.